# julia incorrect type when subtyping parametric supertype

Tags: types, julia

I have an abstract type

```
abstract type PointND{N<:Integer, T<:Number} end
```

When I subtype it, setting `N=1`

```
struct Point1D{T} <: PointND{1, T}
    x::T
end
```

Julia throws error

```
ERROR: TypeError: in PointND, in N, expected N<:Integer, got Int64
```

even though `(typeof(1)<:Integer) == true`.

This happens even when `N` is of type `Number`. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `N` here is not a subtype of `Integer`, but an instance of a subtype of `Integer`. If you actually try `1 <: Integer` in the REPL, it will throw an error. So PointND will only accept types that subtype `Integer`, like `Int` or `UInt`, but not instances of subtypes of `Integer` like `1` or `0xff`. The solution here is actually just not to restrict the type of `N` at all, and document clearly instead that `N` should always be an integer. There isn't currently any way to restrict the type of instances of bit types in type parameters.